# two circles on different cycles

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am not a math person but I am going to try and phrase this according to the rules. You have an object that completes a path every 29,000 years (earth orbit), that object also has a tilt that is on a path every 40,000 years. How many years is it before the tilt and the orbit are back at the same starting point. I hope that is correct because I have tried to look this up and can't find anything that addresses it, and maybe the math behind this is far more complicated than is allowed. Thank you Ken

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple

Answer (score 2):

So, I think this is the easiest way to get a picture. Imagine you have some planet (definitely not the earth, though your question may have come from some other periodic aspect of the earth) and it is orbiting some star, and it takes it 29,000 years to get around. However, this planet also rotates about its axis, like ours does, but it takes 40,000 years to do it. Now, lets say you start off at year 0 with the planet at the far right point of its orbit (we are looking down from above, let's say), and there is a guy sitting on the equator and he is looking out into space in some direction, maybe at some star. The question is when will the earth return to that same space and face that same direction again so that this (now very old) man can look at the same star from this spot on the equator he likes to sit on?

Now here is an equivalent question (can you say why?). You have a very weird clock. One hand goes around every 29,000 years, the other every 40,000 years. Starting in the 12 o'clock position, when will both hands return to that position, so the clock looks the same?

Now lets think about how to solve this. When is the 40,000 year hand at 12 o'clock? Well, first at year 0, then it finally comes back at year 40,000, then again at year 80,000, and so on. And the 29,000 year hand? Well, it also starts a year 0, then comes back at year 29,000, then again at year 58,000, and so on. In your math class, you might have said that the first hand returns at **multiples** of 40,000, and the other hand returns at **multiples** of 29,000. So you want to find the first year that is a **multiple** of both.

Comment: Try googling the word "precession".

Comment: I can see how you broke it down to something simpler. I will go read up on precession

Comment: Based on the assumption that if 29 divides into 40 equally then both clocks are at 12? In that case it would be a 1,160,000 year cycle when both clocks are at 12????

Comment: Is it as simple as just multiplying the two numbers together to find the whole number they both work with? That is not how I went about it, I used a spreadsheet A1 40, A2 80, A3 120, the placed this equation in B1 =A1 /29, B2 =A2 /29, B3 =A3/29, highlighted both columns and started dragging at line 29 I saw the whole number 40 as the result and said wait min. If it was divided equally the hand must be back at 12. The resultant number in A29 was 1,160, well that is 29x40 ... some how I don't think this is correct, I just don't see myself as figuring this out.